# ASP.NET TreeView, select NodeTemplate upon databinding similar to the TemplateSelector in WPF?

Tags: asp.net, templates, treeview

Usage scenario,

I have hierarchically categorized items and I would like to present them in a TreeView. The TreeView will be populated on demand and it contains both the categories and the items, I would like to have different templates for the categories and the items. That is not a problem if the items were static I could easily list them in the aspx markup and specify template for each node, but on demand populating I have no clue how to do it. I don't mind any solution suggesting usage of Telerik TreeView or DevExpress Treeview.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, 
one day and no comment :), I got it done using RadTreeView, the RadTreeNode supports custom attributes, I added a custom attribute to distinguish between a category and an item, and in the NodeTemplate I used MultiView control which chooses the View to display by checking the node custom attribute.

Here is some parts of the code,

```
<telerik:RadTreeView ID="rtvQueries" runat="server" OnNodeExpand="rtvQueries_NodeExpand"
        Skin="Black" OnClientNodeClicking="CheckNodeType" OnNodeClick="rtvQueries_NodeClick">
        <NodeTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfId" runat="server" Value='<%# Container.Value %>' />
            <asp:MultiView ID="mvAll" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex='<%# Container.Attributes["ItemType"] == "C"? 0 : 1 %>'>
                <asp:View ID="vwCategory" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCategory" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.Text %>' />
                </asp:View>
                <asp:View ID="vwQuery" runat="server">
                    <div style="float: left">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblQuery" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.Text %>' />
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px; overflow: hidden; width: 200px;">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCommandText" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.Attributes["CommandText"] %>' />
                    </div>
                </asp:View>
            </asp:MultiView>
        </NodeTemplate>
    </telerik:RadTreeView>
```

The code-behind for NodeExpand,

```
protected void rtvQueries_NodeExpand(object sender, RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
        {
            Guid categoryId = new Guid(e.Node.Value);
            List<Category> cats = DBHelper.GetQueryCategories(categoryId);
            cats.ForEach(c =>
            {
                RadTreeNode n = new RadTreeNode(c.Name, c.Id.ToString());
                n.ExpandMode = TreeNodeExpandMode.ServerSideCallBack;
                n.Attributes["ItemType"] = "C";
                e.Node.Nodes.Add(n);
                n.DataBind();
            });

            List<RightBI.Query> queries = DBHelper.GetQueriesByCategoryId(categoryId);
            queries.ForEach(q =>
            {
                RadTreeNode n = new RadTreeNode(q.Name, q.Id.ToString());
                n.Attributes["ItemType"] = "Q";
                n.Attributes["CommandText"] = q.CommandText;
                e.Node.Nodes.Add(n);
                n.DataBind();
            });
        }
```

The only problem in this solution is I have to call DataBind on each node after adding it to the TreeView so the binding expressions evaluated.

I still would like to see other solutions and comments on this solution or better ideas.